# Upgrading from v2 to v3 results in internal server errors

Tags: craft3, upgrades

I'm trying to upgrade a v2 site to v3 and have done the following:

- Verified that my server meets the v3 requirements using the Craft Server Check.
- Followed steps 1-3 on [this page](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html).
- Followed the directions on [this page](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html).

When I go to my control panel's URL, I get the following error: "An internal server error occurred." There's nothing in my server's "error.log" file.

As a test, I even created a fresh install of v2 on a new server instance, imported my site's data, and tried upgrading that, and I still get the server error.

FWIW, I'm running Apache 2.4, Ubuntu 16.04, PHP 7.0.30, and MySQL v5.7.22.

Comment: I'm guessing the "An internal server error occurred." message is a web-server styled message and not a Craft-styled one?  If so, the underlying error message would be in your web server's error logs, not Craft's.

Comment: have you tried experimenting with the db table prefix setting? you might want to set that to "craft" when running `./craft setup` in the terminal to see if it works.

Comment: @BradBell I've checked my server's Apache error logs and there's nothing in there.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some more digging in `storage/logs`, it turns out that the permissions were incorrect on the "cpresources" director. Once I fixed those, the upgrade progressed as normal.